# Setting global timezone in Angular

Tags: angular

Does anyone know how to set the default timezone app wide?
I need to fix it to 'Europe/London'.  Even if your browser thinks you are in another country.  My dates are in all in UTC from the database.

For example I am in New Zealand and I want to see all the dates in UK/London time as I am making a booking in the UK.

I looked at using a date pipe such as today | date:'full':'GMT-8' but this does not account for daylight savings except for the US.  It states:
"A timezone offset (such as '+0430'), or a standard UTC/GMT or continental US timezone abbreviation. Default is the local system timezone of the end-user's machine."
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

I am currently looking at moment.js but I am not sure how I would incorporate this.  Global would be much easier.

Also the date control I am using is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime if that helps.  Also does not seem to support timezones.

Comment: I think this link(https://praveenlobo.com/blog/how-to-convert-javascript-local-date-to-utc-and-utc-to-local-date/) will help you..

Comment: Thanks @SayanSamanta but I don't want local time I want a specific timezone e.g. for London.

Comment: @MadMac i have similar requirement have you done this ?

Comment: @Eldho No I never figured out how.  I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score -2):

try that code:

```js
import {MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter'
```

...

```js
@NgModule({
  ....
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: {useUtc: true}},
  ]
  ....
})
```

Comment: hi he is looking for New Zealand time zone, can you write a second portion of code, using New zealand time? right now it just says useUtc: true