# Fix date to specific timezone in ng-pick-datetime

Tags: angular

I have an ng-pick-datetime control and I want show all dates in the Europe/London timezone.  My dates are coming from the server as UTC.

e.g. I am in New Zealand and I want to see the dates as local London time as I want to make a booking in London time.  Currently they are showing in New Zealand time.

```
<input 
  class="shadow-input" 
  type="hidden" 
  [(ngModel)]="booking.bookingDate" 
  [owlDateTime]="dt" 
  [min]="minBookingDate" 
  [max]="maxBookingDate"> 

<owl-date-time [pickerMode]="'dialog'" #dt></owl-date-time>

<input 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control pl-2 input-custom input-postpend"
  [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" 
  placeholder="Select Date"
  (focus)="onDateInputClick($event)" 
  (click)="onDateInputClick($event)"
  [min]="minBookingDate" 
  [max]="maxBookingDate" 
  [readonly]="booking.bookingDate"  
  [value]="booking.bookingDate | dateFilter: dateFormat">
```

Note: I also asked if I could change the timezone application wide but I haven't been able to figure that out. [Setting global timezone in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102497/setting-global-timezone-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the documentation for the particular date/time picker that you're using, owl-date-time, and it appears to use standard JavaScript `Date` objects for date and time values.

The problem with that is that `Date` doesn't have very good timezone support. You can't specify Olsen timezones like `Europe/London`. All `Date` understands is the one local timezone of whatever system it's running on, plus UTC.

You'll need to find a date picker designed to work with something like https://momentjs.com/timezone/.

Comment: I'm familiar with momentjs and had a play with the timezone functionality.  It just seems that this is something that would be really common as a lot of web apps work across timezones.  I am really surprised how little support and info I found during my search.  ( I am relatively new to js ).

Comment: I noticed further on in the docs that moment.js is supported as an option for owl-date-time. The emphasis was all on localized formatting, however, with nothing mentioned about timezones.

Comment: I tried it using moment-timezone however the date control just seems to have timezone bugs if you use the calendar.  It works if you only change the time.
I have spent a lot of hours on this. It seems like it should be a common pattern.  I have another app that has loads of dates and I don't even want to think about attempting that one.

Comment: I needed a solution for this problem myself and ended up writing my own date picker, date/time input field, and timezone library. It's a bit specialized for a particular astronomy application, however, so I can't recommend it as a general solution to anyone else.